# Loop through named range and select row and columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a named range that looks like:

[image: named range]

For each row where column 2 equals zero I want to white out the row from columns A:F (the six columns).  What I have does not work as it selects the entire named range and whites the whole thing out when the if statement becomes true.

```
Sub modFinishFinancialEstimate()

Dim myrange As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set myrange = Range("actual_cost_of_svc")
Set ws = ActiveSheet

ws.Select

For i = myrange.Rows(1).row To myrange.Rows.Count
    MsgBox "The Count of services is " & Cells(i, 2).Value
    If Range("B" & i).Value = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The value is " & Cells(i, 2).Value & " and will be whited out"
        For Each col In myrange.Columns
            With Selection.Font
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            ActiveWorkbook.ws.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    myrange), SortOn:=xlSortOnCellColor, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
            With Selection.Sort
                .SetRange myrange
                .Header = xlGuess
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With
        Next col
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

The problem I encounter with the code above is that it checks the first row only and then exits the sub.

Answer (score 0):

The first row will be

```
msgbox myrange.rows(1).row
```

[You don't need to Select anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Alternatively, you could make your loop relative, i.e. the `i`th cell of `myrange` rather than the `i`th cell of the worksheet.